# How often should one go to the dentist?

Tags: health-safety-shmira

The Ketzos Hashulchan 126:3 discusses issues with teeth becoming a concern of protecting one's health. Do Poskim today suggest the frequency one must visit the dentist to preemptively protect one's health or is it only an obligation to go when there is currently an issue?

Comment: Similarly, have any poskim released guidelines for how many IU of vitamin K toddlers should consume daily?

Comment: @DoubleAA Although I wondered whether this question of dentistry would be similar to any other medical guidelines, I thought there might be more of a question since there is such a wide array of dentist suggestions (2x a year, 1x, once every 2 years) depending on one's own habits.

Answer (score 4):

I've heard the authorities of today (e.g. [Rabbi A. Weiss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osher_Weiss)) teach that the Torah expects one to following medical recommendations. Have you consulted your dentalcare professionals regarding this issue?

Comment: Who is Rabbi A. Weiss?

Comment: @Alex https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvdRqMiPfL4